# Error in sending test mail at Hudson Email Notifications

Tags: email, hudson, notifications

I could successfully send e-mail notification in Hudson using gmail as the smtp server.
But when I try to configure our own smtp server, it gives the following error when trying to send the test mail:

```
Failed to send out e-mail

javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Are there any special configurations with the e-mail notifications???

**Edit:**

Also does it require enforcing the security certificate and if so is there a way to achieve it???

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please try using the following settings:

```
SMTP SERVER : smtp.gmail.com
use SMTP Authentication : true
use SSL : true
SMTP port : 465
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. My solution was to make all the necessary configuration (check ssl box and stuff) and CLICK THE SAVE BUTTON before use the test mail.

i just had this issue before clicking the save button.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SMTP port from 587 to 465 also resolved this issue for me, even though I'm using an alternative SMTP service:

```
SMTP server:               smtp.mandrill.com
Use SMTP Authentication:   true
Use SSL:                   true
SMTP Port:                 465
```

From what I can tell *(disclaimer: I am by no means a Hudson/Jenkins expert)*
the Hudson/Jenkins email plugin supports SSL encrypted SMTP communication - however this implementation requires that communications are encrypted from the get go.

When connecting on port 587, the server on the other end may expect a STARTTLS command (see this [SSL vs TLS vs STARTTLS](https://www.fastmail.fm/help/technical/ssltlsstarttls.html) article). This command is sent using plain-text to 'upgrade' the connection to use SSL/TLS.

Hudson/Jenkins instead attempts to start negotiating SSL on port 587, which is promptly rejected, resulting in the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I also tried adding additional JAVA options "-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true" (configured in /etc/default/jenkins on Unbuntu) to enable TLS:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
```

Unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue for me.

After changing the port to 465, the SSL negotiation occurred correctly and the communication succeeded.

Hope that helps.